# Remove product-tag in url for Woocommerce

Tags: php, url, woocommerce, product, permalinks

i need function for Woocommerce to remove "product-tag" in url of product tag.
I search more solutions but dont work and i dont like install plugin for this feature.
Tnks
Regards

I test code but dont work

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your functions.php file to remove the product-tag from the URL:

```php
// Remove product tag base
function my_remove_product_tag_base() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->extra_permastructs['product_tag']['struct'] = '/tag/%tag%';
}
add_action('init', 'my_remove_product_tag_base');
```

Comment: Hi, tnks but dont work

Comment: Navigate to Settings > Permalinks and then scroll all the way bottom to Product permalinks. Here you can change the product url structure.

Comment: Sorry but dont chance the structure of link